# Настраиваемая выборка из базы данных

Tags: asp.net, sql

Здравствуйте. Нужно организовать выборку из базы данных в зависимости от заполненных полей. Например:

1. в БД есть таблица с полями: имя, фамилия, отчетсво.
2. на странице поля: имя, фамилия, отчество.

нужно вот такое: 
**SELECT * FROM table** (если не заполнено ни одно из полей)
**SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name=[[@name](/users/861/namespace)](/users/861/namespace)** (если заполнено поле Имя)
**SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name=[[@name](/users/861/namespace)](/users/861/namespace) AND SecondName=@SecondName** (если заполнены оба поля)
 и т.д.

Есть страница с полями, `SqlDataSource` и кнопкой. Я сделал так: по нажатию на кнопку проверяю значения в полях и создаю для `SqlDataSource FilterExpression`, затем выполняю выборку. Но мне кажется, что мой выбор некорректен.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше сделать подобную выборку или в каком направлении копать?
Спасибо

Comment: При работе с SqlDataSource ваш выбор вполне корректный.

Comment: спасибо. А есть какие-нибудь другие подходы вообще к решению такой задачи, я имею в виду, если не ограничиваться SqlDataSource?

Comment: Использовать ОРМ и на сервере создавать критерии для поиска инфы из БД в терминах используемой ОРМ, или на чистом АДО опять таки на основе заполненных данных генерировать соответственный скл запрос, ну или вариант с хранимкой.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такой вариант, если отсутствие значения - это NULL:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name=coalesce(@name, Name) AND SecondName=coalesce(@SecondName, SecondName)
```

[COALESCE](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_case_statement/page2.html)

Comment: О, то, что нужно, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать такой вариант. Много букв, но true-SQL.

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE (@name is null and @SecondName is null)
  OR (Name = @name AND @name is not null AND @SecondName is null)
  OR ((Name = @name AND SecondName = @SecondName)
    AND @name is not null AND @SecondName is not null
  )
```

Comment: Пробовал я такой вариант, писал хранимую процедуру, но текста действительно многовато получается. если перебирать все варианты. Но за совет все равно спасибо.

Comment: Много текста — не значит плохо.

Comment: Я не говорю, что много текста плохо, но если есть альтернатива, то лучше использовать ее.